# Python add percantace of specific value per group

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
df = age  is_A
      1    True
      1    False
      2    True
      3    True
      3    True
      3    True
      3    False
```

I want to have the ratio of 'is_A' for each age

```
out = age  ratio
       1   0.5
       2    1
       3   0.75
```

What is the most efficient way for that?

Comment: `df.groupby('age')['is_A'].mean().reset_index(name='ratio')`

Comment: Simply use a `mean`: `df.groupby("age")['is_A'].mean()`, or `df.groupby('age', as_index=False).agg(ratio=('is_A', 'mean'))`

Comment: a simple solution.